# Constant "Read Timeout" exception from Micronaut Declarative client

Tags: java, micronaut, completable-future

I have two declarative Clients in my Micronaut app which I'm collecting their results in a non-blocking manner (alongside with some other async methods). But every once in a while they produce `io.micronaut.http.client.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Read Timeout`. Maybe like every 10 or 20 requests it happens, for either one of them, but I'm pretty sure that the external services are not timing out, as they are fast and highly available.

Here's how my clients look like:

```
@Client("https://foo.bar")
public interface ServiceClient {
    @Post("/data/myData")
    CompletableFuture<List<ServiceResponse>> getDataAsync(@NonNull @Body ServiceRequest request);
}
```

And this is how I call them inside an `@Async` method:

```
.
.
@Inject
private Provider<ServiceClient> serviceClient;
.
.
@Async
public CompletableFuture<Map<String, Optional<ServiceResponse>>> getDataAsync() {
    ServiceRequest request = buildRequest(); // Some method

    return serviceClient.get().getDataAsync(request)
            .thenApply(this::parseResponse) // Some method
            .exceptionally(
                    ex -> {
                        LOG.error("Failed to connect to service", ex);
                        return someDefaultMap;
                    }
            );
}
```

And in my main method, I get the results of my declarative clients + some other async methods and combine them together:

```
CompletableFuture<Map<String, Optional<ServiceResponse>>> servideFuture = getDataAsync();
CompletableFuture<Object> future2 = anotherAsyncMethod();
CompletableFuture<Object> future3 = andAnotherAsyncMethod();

CompletableFuture.allOf(servideFuture, future2, future3).thenApply(it -> {
    Map<String, Optional<ServiceResponse>> servieRes = servideFuture.join();
    Object future2Res = future2.join();
    Object future3Res = future3.join();

    // Some aggregation
})
```

I have set a 5 second timeout for my clients, which is more than enough because the other services that I'm calling are pretty fast. I'm also using a cached type for my I/O executor. Here's my configuration:

```
  http:
    client:
      read-timeout: 5s
  executors:
    io:
      type: cached
```

Answer (score 4):

I think I found the problem. It seems like my clients were awaiting in the default event-loop because of the high amount of requests. I defined a custom event-loop just for my declarative clients and now it's running pretty solid.

```
micronaut:
  netty:
    event-loops:
      default:
        num-threads: 3
      httpclient:
        num-threads: 5
  http:
    client:
      read-timeout: 5s
      event-loop-group: httpclient
```

Comment: Any comment about how did you decided the values? (3 for the default num-threads and 5 for the httpclient group)

Comment: @Lobo It strongly depends on your specification. How many HTTP calls your service is expected to make per seconds? How fast are the services that you want to call? You can eventually just start with an initial small number, and if you find out it's too small, just increase it to a point that it's suitable.